# ModemManager Issue with multiple WWAN Sierrawireless Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04, usb-modem

Please let me understand the issue with multiple WWANs frequently disconnecting and reconnecting I am using Sierra wireless modems on the Ubuntu 22.04 desktop.
I have updated the drivers and tried all available internet options, but no luck.
It is not modems are not getting connected, modems are connected but while giving some load on them they start misbehaving (WWANs frequently disconnecting and reconnecting)
I am using the default modem manager app from free Desktop org

Appreciate it if someone could help